# Cannot use Markdown shortcodes in Blogdown's Rmd files

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, blogdown, hugo-shortcode

I am using Blogdown. In my `post.Rmd` file I need to use a shortcode:

```
This is me calling a **shortcode**:

`r blogdown::shortcode("mysc", .content = "Find **more** about this shortcode in [here](https://www.wikipedia.com).")`
```

As you can see, `.content` is Markdown, not plain text. Shortcode `mysc.html` is:

```html
<p class="sc">
  {{ if .Inner }}
    {{ .Inner }}
  {{ end }}
</p>
```

As you can see, I am using `blogdown::shortcode` because [it is not possible to use shortcode syntax in Rmd files](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/40).

#### Problem

However the Markdown in `.content` is not converted into HTML, I get this as output:

```html
<p>
Find **more** about this shortcode in [here](https://www.wikipedia.com).
</p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

#### Troubleshooting

Note that specifying `.type` does not help:

```
`r blogdown::shortcode("mysc", .content = "...", .type = "markdown")`
```

Also it should not be necessary as it defaults to `"markdown"`. And it still renders the same exact output if I specify `.type = "html"`. What the hell is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in [the Github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/40#issuecomment-488107934) you referenced, Hugo changed the behavior of `{{% %}}`. Personally I feel it is a breakage. Before it is fixed, I think your only options are

- Lock your website project to a lower version of Hugo, e.g.

  ```r
  blogdown::install_hugo('0.54.0', force = TRUE)
  ```

  If you installed Hugo via Homebrew previously, you'd better uninstall it: `brew remove hugo`.
- Or manually turn `.Inner` to Markdown in your shortcode: `{{ .Inner | markdownify }}`. Please note that this approach has a potential risk: if the Hugo author decides to revert the behavior of `{{% %}}` shortcodes, you will have to remove `markdownify`.