# Blogdown::Shortcode doesn't work after using emo package in R

Tags: emoji, blogdown, hugo-shortcode

I am using Blogdown and want to use a shortcode in an Rmd file. I am using shortcodes in a chunk, not in an inline code.
I saw this question [Cannot use Markdown shortcodes in Blogdown's Rmd files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55856904/12522221) and the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55928449/12522221. But I am not sure if my problem is related to that because:

This code works. There is an inline code and an embedded youtube video with a shortcode.

````
```{r}
x = 5      
```

For a circle with the radius `r x`,
its area is `r pi * x^2`.

```{r echo=FALSE}
blogdown::shortcode('youtube', 'pQHX-SjgQvQ')
```
````

This code doesn't work when using inline code with emo package.

````
`r emo::ji('wink')`

```{r echo=FALSE}
blogdown::shortcode('youtube', 'pQHX-SjgQvQ')
```
````

What is the problem? emo package? the behavior of `{{% %}}` in Hugo? Any way to fix this? It is not super important but I want to learn the reason.